# What is the correct use of package.lock.json file, when exactly it works

Tags: npm, npm-install, package.json

What is the exact use of `package.lock.json` file? I have read about it but it's confusing.

1. Let's say I do `npm install` so that it will create a `package.lock.json` file, and the next time when I do `npm install`, will it retain installation of the same packages as it was mentioned in the `package.lock.json` file?
2. Let's say I have a package version defined as `"^1.0.0"` in my `package.json` file and a new version becomes available in the npm registry. Will it update the package when I do `npm install`, or will it keep the same as what was there in the `package.json`?
3. Is there any easy way to update the `package.json` file with the exact no of package version without manually updating it one by one? I want to keep maintain the version of the package the same so that next time anybody does npm install, they should get exactly the same package. It's need for a release branch

Actually I need what was the original definition of `package.lock.json` file but I found inconsistency in its behavior.

I tried using NPM CI but it fails with error node_gyp needs python https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/1977

Comment: Did you read the documentation https://docs.npmjs.com/configuring-npm/package-lock-json.html?

Comment: Yes I have gone through it, it's not helping, it seems like I will get new package even if lock file is present

Comment: It seems like npm ci is the command to use to get exact package but that also fails as I mentioned

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What is the exact use of package.lock.json file?

**Ans:** The file is used to describe the exact tree that was generated initially, that is the version of the dependency that was used initially to install (NOTE: It will always be modified if package.json or node_modules are modified by npm)

source: https://docs.npmjs.com/configuring-npm/package-lock-json.html

Now coming to your specific questions :

1. Let's say I do `npm install` so that it will create a `package.lock.json` file, and the next time when I do npm install, will it retain installation of the same packages as it was mentioned in the `package.lock.json` file?

   The simple answer here is: Yes

   When you do `npm install` initially, you specify the package name. npm will create `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` file and the entry of the package with the version that was used to install will be added.  next time when you do npm install, without specifying the package it will not update any of your package even with the `caret (^)` symbol  because this time npm will look at the `package-lock.json` file (as it is present there) and it will install the same version that is specified in the (`package-lock.json`) file.
2. Let's say I have a package version defined as `"^1.0.0"` in my `package.json` file and a new version becomes available in the npm registry.  Will it update the package when I do npm install, or will it keep the same as what was there in the `package.json`?

   As explained in first question, it will not, if the `package-lock.json` is present in the directory.  Updating of the package will only happen if `package-lock.json` file and `node_modules` folder are not present in the directory.
3. Is there any easy way to update the `package.json` file with the exact  no of package version without manually updating it one by one? I want to keep  maintain the version of the package the same so that next time anybody does `npm install`,  they should get exactly the same package. It's need for a release branch

   It is a good practice to use `npm ci`, but you can also use `npm update`,  this will update the dependencies to its latest minor version, and your `package.json` as well as `package-lock.json` file will also be updated

For the production, its preferred way to use the same version of dependencies that was used initially. In this case it is better to have `package-lock.json` file, so in case of `dockerizing` application when you do `npm install` it will install the dependencies with versions that are used in `package-lock.json`

Comment: regarding the second point, does node_module folder need to be there to make use of lock file or if say the new package is 1.0.1 which still satisfies the ^1.0.0 and in package.lock.json its 1.0.0 and node-module folder not available, will it install package 1.0.1 or 1.0.0

Comment: node_modules folder does not need to be there to make use of package-lock.json, the file can exist independently, so when you do npm install in such directory it will install the dependency version that is present in package-lock.json, which will be 1.0.0, however if you deliberately change version in package.json to 1.0.1 it will install 1.0.1 (or the latest minor version) and also update package-lock.json dependency entry to 1.0.1